# Modifiers in 2.93 not rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

Doesn't seem to render the modifiers... somehow. Did I do something wrong?
Edit: I should not do such things at 5 am... how could I miss the render port?
(Blend file included)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your view port subdivisions are a lot higher than your render ones. Change that 2 to a 7 and it should work.

[image]